# MySQL query running extremely slow

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have this query which give me some head pains:

```
SELECT   SEARCH_TREE.STR_LEVEL,
ELT(SEARCH_TREE.STR_LEVEL, DES_TEXTS.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS2.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS3.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS4.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS5.TEX_TEXT) AS STR_TEXT,
ELT(SEARCH_TREE.STR_LEVEL, SEARCH_TREE.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE2.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE3.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE4.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE5.STR_ID) AS STR_ID,
ELT(SEARCH_TREE.STR_LEVEL-1, DES_TEXTS.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS2.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS3.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS4.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS5.TEX_TEXT) AS STR_TEXT2,
ELT(SEARCH_TREE.STR_LEVEL-1, SEARCH_TREE.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE2.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE3.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE4.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE5.STR_ID) AS STR_ID2,
ELT(SEARCH_TREE.STR_LEVEL-2, DES_TEXTS.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS2.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS3.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS4.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS5.TEX_TEXT) AS STR_TEXT3,
ELT(SEARCH_TREE.STR_LEVEL-2, SEARCH_TREE.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE2.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE3.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE4.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE5.STR_ID) AS STR_ID3,
ELT(SEARCH_TREE.STR_LEVEL-3, DES_TEXTS.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS2.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS3.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS4.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS5.TEX_TEXT) AS STR_TEXT4,
ELT(SEARCH_TREE.STR_LEVEL-3, SEARCH_TREE.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE2.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE3.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE4.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE5.STR_ID) AS STR_ID4,
ELT(SEARCH_TREE.STR_LEVEL-4, DES_TEXTS.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS2.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS3.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS4.TEX_TEXT, DES_TEXTS5.TEX_TEXT) AS STR_TEXT5,
ELT(SEARCH_TREE.STR_LEVEL-4, SEARCH_TREE.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE2.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE3.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE4.STR_ID, SEARCH_TREE5.STR_ID) AS STR_ID5
FROM                  SEARCH_TREE
LEFT JOIN DESIGNATIONS ON DESIGNATIONS.DES_ID = SEARCH_TREE.STR_DES_ID AND DESIGNATIONS.DES_LNG_ID = 21
LEFT JOIN DES_TEXTS ON DES_TEXTS.TEX_ID = DESIGNATIONS.DES_TEX_ID
LEFT JOIN SEARCH_TREE AS SEARCH_TREE2 ON SEARCH_TREE2.STR_ID = SEARCH_TREE.STR_ID_PARENT
LEFT JOIN DESIGNATIONS AS DESIGNATIONS2 ON DESIGNATIONS2.DES_ID = SEARCH_TREE2.STR_DES_ID AND DESIGNATIONS2.DES_LNG_ID = 21
LEFT JOIN DES_TEXTS AS DES_TEXTS2 ON DES_TEXTS2.TEX_ID = DESIGNATIONS2.DES_TEX_ID
LEFT JOIN SEARCH_TREE AS SEARCH_TREE3 ON SEARCH_TREE3.STR_ID = SEARCH_TREE2.STR_ID_PARENT
LEFT JOIN DESIGNATIONS AS DESIGNATIONS3 ON DESIGNATIONS3.DES_ID = SEARCH_TREE3.STR_DES_ID AND DESIGNATIONS3.DES_LNG_ID = 21
LEFT JOIN DES_TEXTS AS DES_TEXTS3 ON DES_TEXTS3.TEX_ID = DESIGNATIONS3.DES_TEX_ID
LEFT JOIN SEARCH_TREE AS SEARCH_TREE4 ON SEARCH_TREE4.STR_ID = SEARCH_TREE3.STR_ID_PARENT
LEFT JOIN DESIGNATIONS AS DESIGNATIONS4 ON DESIGNATIONS4.DES_ID = SEARCH_TREE4.STR_DES_ID AND DESIGNATIONS4.DES_LNG_ID = 21
LEFT JOIN DES_TEXTS AS DES_TEXTS4 ON DES_TEXTS4.TEX_ID = DESIGNATIONS4.DES_TEX_ID
LEFT JOIN SEARCH_TREE AS SEARCH_TREE5 ON SEARCH_TREE5.STR_ID = SEARCH_TREE4.STR_ID_PARENT
LEFT JOIN DESIGNATIONS AS DESIGNATIONS5 ON DESIGNATIONS5.DES_ID = SEARCH_TREE5.STR_DES_ID AND DESIGNATIONS5.DES_LNG_ID = 21
LEFT JOIN DES_TEXTS AS DES_TEXTS5 ON DES_TEXTS5.TEX_ID = DESIGNATIONS5.DES_TEX_ID
ORDER BY    STR_TEXT,   STR_TEXT2,  STR_TEXT3,  STR_TEXT4,  STR_TEXT5 LIMIT 1;
```

When I running this script, phpmyadmin show "loading" and remain stucked.

How can I fix this?

Responsible for this issue may be "ELT" function?

Please help...this it's very important for me to finish a project.

Best regards,
Razvan

Comment: Its too many joins. You need to redesign the database.

Comment: If the tables have the correct indexes to help the joins then it might be a good design - can't tell from the information here. You need to get the query plan: run EXPLAIN SELECT......and post the results.

Comment: thanks simon....GIVE ME A answer to chose you for this question